# oscap-ssh scanning ubuntu22.04 Result notapplicable

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, openscap

please tell me if there are any options to check the workstation on ubuntu22.04 using openscap. I downloaded ssg for Ubuntu22.04, but when I try to check, I get a Result notapplicable on all points.....I scan remotely, using oscap-ssh. do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You missed the chance to tel us the exact oscap command you have employed.

In general the notapplicable result of XCCDF scan means that oval implementation referenced by CPE referenced by XCCDF is not matching the scanned system. In short, the policy you are trying to use is immediatelly applicable to your target system.